# dispatch to redux when screen size is for I.e. large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a confusing issue where I want to update a portion of the state of the header when it gets to screen size large. I'm currently using tailwind so I have the following code:

Where when in mobile view, if the template is not hidden, and the screen size gets to large-- the state should automatically get updated with handleHideTemplates...

That's what I'm attempting to do. I understand with this the handle is fired immediately which I don't want...

in mobile view, if the person hits showTemplates, it hides templates immediately.

```js
  const handleHideTemplates = () => {
    dispatch(setShowTemplates({ hidden: 'hidden' }));
    dispatch(setTemplateMargin({ margin: '' }));
  };

  console.log('hidden', hidden);

  return (
    <header
      className={`text-gray-500 text-semibold text-s fill-accent1 
      top-0 z-30 sticky  lg:grid ${
        'grid' ? handleHideTemplates() : null
      } bg-templateBg px-8 ${margin}`}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... instead of conditional inside class..

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
        handleHideTemplates();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
```